# Auto import of npm packages in Visual Studio code

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code doesn't import any npm package with default exports. I'm using ES6 (no TS)

This is my code:

```
const apiURL = "https://localhost:8000";

frisby.globalSetup({
  request: {
    json: true,
    baseUrl: apiURL,
  },
});

axios.defaults.baseURL = apiURL;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

When I wrote frisby it doesn't suggested the import and `ctrl+.`doesn't work either
[image: frisby import doesnt work]

[image: axios import doesnt work]

And my package.json has this:

```
{
  "name": "ApiTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Luis",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@types/frisby": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.6",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "frisby": "^2.1.1",
    "jest": "^24.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

I want that VSCode suggest me to import

```
import axios from 'axios';
import frisby from 'frisby';
```

I installed `auto import` and `npm intellisense` but doesn't work for me, what can I do?